# Custom Options not updating price - JS error

Tags: magento-1.9, price

I've come across a bit of a strange error when making products with custom items. This happens for both simple items and bundle items with fixed prices. When selecting one of the custom items, the 'Price As Configured' value will not update, instead it throws up the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: optionsPrice.addCustomPrices is not a function
```

When you add the product to the basket the correct price is displayed, but the live price on the product page is not. If the product is a bundle, then changing the 'bundle items' will update the price as you'd expect.

I've tried displaying the page in the default package/theme to make sure there were no layout changes, and the only non-standard extension I have installed is Worldpay. Can anyone offer any suggestions as to where the problem may be?