# Magento 1.9.2.4: Custom Options price not changing

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options

I got this issue where Price is not updated when checking the custom options (Fixed Price: +400).

I got this error:

```
TypeError: Product.OptionsPrice is not a constructor

TypeError: optionsPrice is undefined
```

[image: error in custom options price not updated]

Related questions:
[Custom Options not updating price - JS error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86975/custom-options-not-updating-price-js-error)

[Custom Option Price Not Updating](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130655/custom-option-price-not-updating)

[Custom Option Price is not changing](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90033/custom-option-price-is-not-changing)

[Update product custom option price on product price change](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104582/update-product-custom-option-price-on-product-price-change)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It happened to me after upgrading to magento 1.9.3.
In my custom theme was missing product_options.js call.
You need to add

```
<action method="addJs"><script>varien/product_options.js</script></action>
```

Check catalog.xml and configurableswatches.xml in rwd theme for reference.
You will also need to copy

```
\skin\frontend\rwd\default\js\configurableswatches\configurable-swatch-prices.js
```

to

```
\skin\frontend\yourTheme\default\js\configurableswatches\
```

Hope can help

Comment: Thanks this fixed the error message in console but still it doesn't change/update the price when checking it. Any idea?

Comment: @nhinzky as i said it works for me in Magento 1.9.3. What I noticed that it was only update product-price-id class not product-price-id_clone. I solved this by changing `'idSuffix'            => ''` with  `'idSuffix'            => '_clone'` in app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Helper\Product\Type\Composite.php line 130